# Java program for credit card, ATM payments

Tags: java

I wrote a Java POS program, and the my client wants to add a feature where a person can use a credit card or ATM card for payment. What I understood was that she wants the POS to handle the payment processing. But I noticed in dept stores that they had separate machine where the cards are swiped for the payment, and they get a copy of the receipt. I wonder if you can integrate that feature in the program. If it is possible, are there any specific libraries I can use for that feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would need to contact your client's credit card processor and see if they have an internet gateway and library/API available. Many do.

Answer (score 2):

`@Jairo`, The services you want to avail is called Merchant Acquiring Service. For `online payment` or for using the `POS systems`, one need to contact Acquiring Service Provider (such as TSYS, FDMS etc.) where your client need to register the POS and start the transaction. For More information, just google `"Merchant Acquiring"`.

Hope this will help.